# SQL Server Find Least Privilege for user account

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions

I have a vendor who has installed an application database on one of my SQL Server 2012 instances. He has told me that the SQL Auth account used by the application requires DB Data reader, Data writer, DB owner, and sysadmin. This makes no sense to me because sysadmin would not need the other roles. After install I removed sysadmin and the account had data reader and writer. The application stopped working.

So I am looking for some tips and ideas for figuring out the least privilege required for the application user. I see that the database has stored procedures but there aren't any functions, types, assemblies so I would like to just create a role with all of the required grants. DB Owner would be better than sysadmin. I could live with that.

Comment: even I granted db owner in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the application needs to do. If your application was only reading data, then the datareader role. If it reads and writes to the database, both reader and writer would be good. Note that writing data only includes inserting and updating, not modifying or altering. In most cases, you can assign a series of roles and not provide the login access to commands such as truncating or dropping tables - it's obvious why an application having god powers would be a bad idea.

Here's a list of all the possible roles you can assign and what each of them is for. Hopefully understanding what the application does will help you assign these roles more fluidly.

**Predefined database roles**

You may need to create your own, but you have access to several predefined database roles:

- db_owner: Members have full access.
- db_accessadmin: Members can manage Windows groups and SQL Server logins.
- db_datareader: Members can read all data.
- db_datawriter: Members can add, delete, or modify data in the tables.
- db_ddladmin: Members can run dynamic-link library (DLL) statements.
- db_securityadmin: Members can modify role membership and manage permissions.
- db_bckupoperator: Members can back up the database.
- db_denydatareader: Members can’t view data within the database.
- db_denydatawriter: Members can’t change or delete data in tables or views.

**Fixed roles**

The fixed server roles are applied serverwide, and there are several predefined server roles:

- SysAdmin: Any member can perform any action on the server.
- ServerAdmin: Any member can set configuration options on the server.
- SetupAdmin: Any member can manage linked servers and SQL Server startup options and tasks.
- Security Admin: Any member can manage server security.
- ProcessAdmin: Any member can kill processes running on SQL Server.
- DbCreator: Any member can create, alter, drop, and restore databases.
- DiskAdmin: Any member can manage SQL Server disk files.
- BulkAdmin: Any member can run the bulk insert command.

Comment: Thanks Horkrine. I had been hoping that db owner would be sufficient but after continuing to look into this I was reminded that db owner does not come with the permissions to execute stored procedures. So I have run the following statement: GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO someuser We are going to try a test during the next maintenance window. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database role to be able to execute stored procedures. It'll even show up in the UI when you grant permissions to a login for a specific database:

```
    -- Create a db_executor role
    CREATE ROLE db_executor
    -- Grant execute rights to the new role
    GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
```